# How to delay USPS by one day? (we won't be able to actually package and send until the next day)

Tags: usps

```
Magento 1.9.3.7
```

We started using USPS as the only shipping method.

*We are unable to ship on the day the customer places the order* (**we ship the next day**).

How can we set it up so that USPS takes that into consideration when showing the quotes for:

```
Priority Mail
Retail Ground
```

**I guess we need the customer to have the right expectation as to when the package will arrive.**